# JQuery clearInterval refuse to working

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery `function` that when it runs a `setInterval function` is called and a div is also `display:block;` But I want the interval to stop when the div is `display:none`. I tried 3 different attempts. The first attempt says `stp not defined` and `strt not defined` in my `console.log`, but the other 2 isn't working.

1. First Attempt

   ```
   function runner(){
       document.getElementById("x").style.display='block';
       var strt = setInterval (function(){
           $("div").show();
       }, 1000);
       var stp = setInterval (function(){
           $("div").hide();
       }, 1000);
   }

   //then I attempt to clearInterval outside the runner function

   x = document.getElementById("x");
   if(x.style.display == "none"){
       clearInterval(stp);
       clearInterval(strt);
   }
   ```
2. Second Attempt

   ```
   function runner(){
       document.getElementById("x").style.display='block';
       var strt = setInterval (function(){
           $("div").show();
       }, 1000);
       var stp = setInterval (function(){
           $("div").hide();
       }, 1000);

       // I attempt to clearInterval inside the runner function

       x = document.getElementById("x");
       if(x.style.display == "none"){
           clearInterval(stp);
           clearInterval(strt);
       }
   }
   ```
3. Final Attempt

   ```
   function runner(){
       document.getElementById("x").style.display='block';

       // I attempt to clearInterval inside the setInterval function

       var strt = setInterval (function(){
           x = document.getElementById("x");
           if(x.style.display == "block"){
               $("div").show();
           } else {
               clearInterval(strt);
           }               
       }, 1000);

       var stp = setInterval (function(){
           x = document.getElementById("x");
           if(x.style.display == "block"){
               $("div").hide();
           } else {
               clearInterval(stp);
           }               
       }, 1000);

   }
   ```

   My aim is when the `runner function` is running the the `div` keeps on blinking off and on every 1sec and I want it to stop as soon as `x.style.display == "none"` Please How do I run my code?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve. You're running 2 delayed functions that to try to show and hide the DIV element simultaneously. Also, if you want to stop on x.style.display == "none", you won't get any blinking, as animation will stop on the very first div.hide() call. Can you elaborate?

Comment: If you want blinking, use [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) in an interval.

Comment: First attempt can't possibly work due to scope of variables that are local inside `runner()` only and not available outside of it

Comment: Objective doesn't even make sense. How can it blink every second but turn off interval when it is hidden? Would turn off first time it is hidden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the issue. The first attempt works fine but I need to define the `strt` and `stp` variables before running the function like this

```
var start;
var stp;
function runner (){
    //blah blah blah
}
```